# Using OpenCV to detect a finger tip instead of a face

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using the facedetect example and going from there. Right now it only detects faces. Could someone point me in the direction to detect finger tips. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a simple bright fluorescent sticker on the finger tip with a black dot in center or something like that. or even fashion a finger cap with a pattern printed on it which can be easily differentiated by the camera and your problem is very much solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could use cvFindContours and then check each contour to see if it could be a finger tip and go from there.

It might be easier if you do some pre-processing of the image so that the finger tips stand out, for example mask out colors that don't match the fingers.

Answer (score 1):

http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/finger-tip-extraction-td3870910.html

i was also looking for that. i am going to implement the above one.. :) i think it will help you as well..

Cheers !